# SQL Oracle - 50 records for each agent for previous month

Tags: sql, oracle, limit-per-group

I've a table (processed_amounts) which shows 'amount', 'date_processed', and the 'agent' which processed the amount. I need a query which will pull through a specified number of processed entries, for instance, 50 processed entries, for a specified period, for instance, the previous month, for a list of several agents. Is there a way of writing this all in one query, as I'll be running this monthly? So say I needed a report of 50 entries each for 10 different agents, which were processed  during the month of May 2018, could I fit this into one query?

So, for example, the table looks below;

```
Date_Processed │ Amount │ Agent   
01/05/2018     │ £35:90 │ tbrown  
25/05/2018     │ £79:00 │ asmith
```

My query would need to pull through 50 entries for both tbrown and asmith for May 2018.

Many thanks, for your help

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select pa.*
from (select pa.*,
             row_number() over (partition by agent order by ?) as seqnum
      from processed_amounts pa
      where agent in ( . . . ) and -- list of agents here
            date_processed >= '2018-05-01' and
            date_processed < '2018-06-01'
     ) pa
where seqnum <= 50;
```

The `?` is for the column that determines *which* 50 you want -- the first in the month, the last, arbitrary 50, random 50 and so on.  If you don't care which 50, you can just put in `agent` for an arbitrary 50 rows.